# J-Meter performance test results varies a lot for Home Wifi & Office Lan Networks. Why?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, network-traffic

I have recorded a Test over VPN and run it successfully in J-Meter 4.0. I have tested it with different loads in my office via the Office Lan Network and also from my home over my home wifi. BUT My confusion is that for the same test with identical load and everything, I am getting very different performance testing results.

I will say the performance tests done via by Office LAN network is more accurate as I can check that manually as well. But the tests done over my home wifi when I am working from home, for the exact same test with same load, gives much better and improved performance test results which is inaccurate. When I gave 300 users load in Office LAN, the application broke & gave horrible results. In my Home wifi, the same test was giving good results. Can please someone explain why this happening and how I can fix this??

**Office LAN Network**: [Average response times (ART)]

20  User test for 2 mins: 2.2 seconds, 0% Error
300 User test for 3 mins: 45.1 seconds, 25% Error

**Home Wifi**: [Average response times (ART)]

20  User test for 2 mins: 1.1 seconds, 0% Error
300 User test for 3 mins: 1.4 seconds, 0% Error

Answer (score 0):

System and network resource play a very crucial role in performance testing. Different system and network are bound to produce different results. You need to check the error for more info and need to find out the reason. Internet bandwidth and network congestion can also be the possible causes of the errors.

Check the servers log, event log to get more information on the errors, if it is not clear from the jmeter csv report.

Hope it helps.